# Mongodb Compound index and sorting

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have this collection :

```
db.place.find() : 
    {
    _id : "p1",
    alterNames : ["abcd","abcD"],
    population : 122
    }
    {
    _id : "p2",
    alterNames : ["qsdf","qsDF"],
    population : 100
    }
```

I want to find documents having **alterNames** starting with "ab" and sort them by **population**.
I created this **index** : `{alterNames : 1, population : -1}`

My query :

```
db.place.find({alterNames : /^ab/}).sort({population : -1}).limit(10).explain()
```

I was waiting to see `"n" = "nScannedObjects" = 10`
What I got :

```
"n" = 10
"nScannedObjects" = 4765
```

Did I miss a thing?

Edit : 
Here is the full explain :

```
db.place.find({alterNames : /^pari/ }).sort({population : -1}).limit(10).explain()

      "clauses" : [
              {
                      "cursor" : "BtreeCursor alterNames_1_population_-1",
                      "isMultiKey" : true,
                      "n" : 10,
                      "nscannedObjects" : 4765,
                      "nscanned" : 4883,
                      "scanAndOrder" : true,
                      "indexOnly" : false,
                      "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                      "indexBounds" : {
                              "alterNames" : [
                                      [
                                              "pari",
                                              "parj"
                                      ],
                                      [
                                              /^pari/,
                                              /^pari/
                                      ]
                              ],
                              "population" : [
                                      [
                                              {
                                                      "$maxElement" : 1
                                              },
                                              {
                                                      "$minElement" : 1
                                              }
                                      ]
                              ]
                      }
              },
              {
                      "cursor" : "BtreeCursor ",
                      "isMultiKey" : false,
                      "n" : 0,
                      "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                      "nscanned" : 0,
                      "scanAndOrder" : true,
                      "indexOnly" : false,
                      "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                      "indexBounds" : {
                              "alterNames" : [
                                      [
                                              "pari",
                                              "parj"
                                      ],
                                      [
                                              /^pari/,
                                              /^pari/
                                      ]
                              ],
                              "population" : [
                                      [
                                              {
                                                      "$maxElement" : 1
                                              },
                                              {
                                                      "$minElement" : 1
                                              }
                                      ]
                              ]
                      }
              }
      ],
      "cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
      "n" : 10,
      "nscannedObjects" : 4765,
      "nscanned" : 4883,
      "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4765,
      "nscannedAllPlans" : 4883,
      "scanAndOrder" : false,
      "nYields" : 890,
      "nChunkSkips" : 0,
      "millis" : 396,
      "server" : "localhost:27017",
      "filterSet" : false
```

Answer (score 1):

Your notation is confusing. I'm assuming your collection consists of documents that look like the two documents in the `places` array.

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : "p1", "alterNames" : [ "abcd", "abcD" ], "population" : 122 }
{ "_id" : "p2", "alterNames" : [ "qsdf", "qsDF" ], "population" : 100 }
```

For a left-anchored regex like `/^ab/`, MongoDB converts the query to one that's actually a range query and can efficiently use the index

```
{ "alterNames" : /^ab/ } => { "alterNames" : { "$gte" : "ab", "$lt" : "ac" } }
```

Each value that matches the range, for example `"abcd"`, has an index of `population` values below it for documents with an `alterNames` (multikey) value of `"abcd"`. To return the matching documents in `population`-order, MongoDB has to externally sort the documents returned from each matching bucket. I believe that's the source of your higher nscannedObjects. If you check the explain (which would have been nice to include in its entirety), you should find `scanAndOrder : true`.

Comment: Yes its a collection of document like you said And no scanAndOrder is false.
I added the full explain.

Comment: `scanAndOrder` is true for the query clauses.

Comment: Oops you're right. Is there any other way to do it more efficiently?